# how to keep GKE cluster nodes in different regions?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible in GKE to create a cluster with its nodes located in multiple regions?

I am aware of Zonal and Regional clusters in which we can have nodes ( and even masters) in different zones. I am wondering if there is a way in GKE to create a multi-regional cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite, but what you can do is front clusters in different regions with a single Google Cloud Load Balancing instance with multi-cluster Ingress:
[multi-cluster-ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress)

The load balancer will route requests to the cluster with the lowest latency for the end user.The Google Cloud Load Balancer is also able to detect if one of the clusters is unavailable and route traffic to the other clusters.